# how to parse the record into json data

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

i have a json data which are :

```
var data_work_in = [     
{"A":999,"B":144,"D":"A","E":""},
{"A":999,"B":36,"D":"B","E":""},
{"A":999,"B":36,"D":"W","E":""}
];
```

I want to use foreach loop to fill the "E" record by this condition

```
if (data_work_in.D === data_work_in[data_work_in.D]
&&
data_work_in[data_work_in.D] === "999")

E = 1

else

E = 0
```

when i try to see the content of the key by the content of other key as below :

```
    json.forEach(e=>{
      console.log(e.[e.A]);

    });
```

i have this error :

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token [

Please help

Comment: remove the dot before the bracket. either dot or bracket as property accessor.

Comment: it's ok for the error but still i don't know how to effect 1 or 0 value to E record

Comment: JSON stands for javascript object notation. it is a way to represent javascript objects via text. You are hard coding a javascript object literal, not JSON.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of things wrong here.  First is that your `console.log` statement contains a syntax error -- the error you're seeing:

```
console.log(e.[e.A]); // syntax error
```

should be

```
console.log(e[e.A]); // cleaned
```

Second, I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to accomplish with the following:

```
data_work_in.D === data_work_in[data_work_in.D]
```

This test will always fail, because there is no member `D` in the array `data_work_in`.

Answer (score 0):

i think you mean to this

```js
var data_work_in = [     
{"A":999,"B":144,"D":"A","E":""},
{"A":999,"B":36,"D":"B","E":""},
{"A":999,"B":36,"D":"W","E":""}
];

for(let i = 0; i < data_work_in.length; i++){ 
    for(key in data_work_in[i]){
        if(key === "D"){
            if(data_work_in[i][data_work_in[i][key]] === 999)
              data_work_in[i].E = 1;
            else
              data_work_in[i].E = 0;
        }    
    }
}

console.log(data_work_in)
// result 
// 0: {A: 999, B: 144, D: "A", E: 1}
// 1: {A: 999, B: 36, D: "B", E: 0}
// 2: {A: 999, B: 36, D: "W", E: 0}
```

Answer (score -1):

You could check the value (with a strict comparison, you need the same type, a number) and assign a numerical value of a boolean check.

```js
var data_work_in = [{ A: 999, B: 144, D: "A", E: ""  }, { A: 999, B: 36, D: "B", E: ""  }, { A: 999, B: 36, D: "W", E: "" }];

data_work_in.forEach(o => o.E = +(o[o.D] === 999));

console.log(data_work_in);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: This user seems to be learning the very basics of programming. Recommending squashing multiple operations and using shorthand seems like a very bad idea.